# Spectrogram example in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, spectrogram

Is there Matlab code that shows a series of numbers representing a waveform as a spectrogram?

The time interval each sample represents is the same, idearly this could also be given to use for the axis scale.

[image: http://www.davegrossman.net/gould/media/spectrum-devocalized.jpg]

For example:

```
spec({1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2}, 0.1 seconds)
```

or

```
spec(my_data.txt, 10 Hz)
```

etc...

Comment: Yes, there's an example here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/signal/ref/spectrogram.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the Signal Processing Toolbox, then you can use the [`spectrogram()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) function.  e.g.:

```
T = 0:0.001:2;
X = chirp(T,100,1,200,'q');
spectrogram(X,128,120,128,1E3);
```

(Example taken from that documentation page.)

The numeric params are window length, overlap length, FFT length and sampling frequency, respectively.

Comment: And for external data it's X = cell2mat({1 2 3 etc...}) or paste into the Workspace window.

Comment: @alan2here: What is "external data"?  `cell2mat` seems excessive; just use square brackets if you want a normal array.

Comment: External data, you know, data that comes from somewhere else. Like a list of numbers I've downloaded from the internet instead of generating in Matlab. Also cell2mat works, using square brackets instead generates "X must be a vector (either row or column)."  because X ends up being the wrong type for spectrogram.

Comment: @alan2here: `X = [1 2 3 4 5 6]; spectrogram(X,...);` should work fine.  In general, you should [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html) (i.e. arrays declared using `{}`) unless you really need them, because they screw up all sorts of things.

Answer (score 0):

if you look on tftb toolbox, the tfrspwv is a very complex and precise spectrogram code and there is an running script example in the tfrspwv.m code online for making a spectrogram in Matlab.